# Printing a webpage using PHP or jQuery

Tags: printing

I have a webpage with header footer and all. when i print that page , i need to print with custom header and footer and specific page size also.. what all should i take into effect for this..

which one is better. by using php or using jquery plugins. i want more control on page layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use CSS maybe, and a special stylesheet for printable versions :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

Comment: how do i disable the browser settings .like the file name which comes at beginning and bottom the date and page number?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your data using PHP from a DB you can use [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)